# Dependency injection and base classes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is in a xamarin.forms app using Prism, but the question is more a foundational c# question that I am confusing myself over.

I am using dependency injection and my types are registered in the app.xaml.cs file -> RegisterTypes method.

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<BusyDialog, BusyDialogViewModel>();

        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    }
```

My base view model ctor is defined as:

```
    public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        NavigationService = navigationService;
        DialogService = dialogService;
    }
```

And all the other viewmodels derive this base class. Eg.

```
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService)
        : base(navigationService, dialogService)
    {
    }
```

My question is that, in this MainPage ctor, I am injecting 'INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService'. Across all my viewmodels I am using NavigationService and DialogService (from the base class) so isn't this redundant code?

I have about 20 viewmodels, I added the IDialogService to my baseclass and realized that I have to update the constructors in every viewmodel.

Is there a way to just inject into the baseclass and usable by all classes that derive this baseclass without having to specify in the class constructors?

Comment: derive class needs to specify in case of parameters that which constructor to invoke in base

Comment: No, you can't inject into a base class. When you derive from a class and it has a non empty ctor, derived class is responsible for calling parent class ctor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor Dependency Injection in Base Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138924/constructor-dependency-injection-in-base-class)

Comment: @Cheesebaron doesn't look like there is an accepted answer in the link you provided either. My question still stands.

Comment: It is probably because there is no definitive answer. Pick the solution _you_ prefer. Either you use a "middleware" class which has all the dependencies and you call them through that. Or you simply add `base()` calls to all your inheriting classes. Another alternative would be to use composition over inheritance. Which one is "best" is primarily opinion based...

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to inject dependencies into a base type is to define a new type to hold onto all the dependencies;

```cs
public class ViewModelBaseDependencies{
    public ViewModelBaseDependencies(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService){
    //...
}
public ViewModelBase(ViewModelBaseDependencies dependencies)
{
    NavigationService = dependencies.NavigationService;
    DialogService = dependencies.DialogService;
}
public MainPageViewModel(ViewModelBaseDependencies dependencies)
        : base(dependencies)
```

Then you only need to pass the one constructor argument and can trivially add new dependencies.

Comment: I'm not following. Where would this class be? How would my baseviewmodel and other derived classes know about this? Can you modify your example with a ViewModelBase and a MainPageViewModel:ViewModelBase please?

Comment: Added constructors to example

Comment: The Navigation/DialogService are defined in my ViewModelBaseDependencies as the properties. So my ViewModelBase would not have a property of type Navigation/DialogService.     public class ViewModelBaseDependencies
    {
        public INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }
        public IDialogService DialogService { get; private set; }

        public ViewModelBaseDependencies(INavigationService navigationService, IDialogService dialogService)
        {
            NavigationService = navigationService;
            DialogService = dialogService;
        }
    }